# Take inverse of a function in Racket

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I am trying to write a higher-order Racket function that takes a first-order function of one variable and returns its inverse.  I know that it has to start off something like this:

```
(let [(inverse (lambda (f)
                 (lambda (y)
                   ... )))])
```

I figured this because `inverse` must take a function which returns a function which takes a `y` and returns `x` such that `(= (f x) y)`. In other words, the contract for inverse is something like:

```
; inverse : (number? -> number?) -> (number? -> number?)
```

I'm just stumped trying to figure out what goes where the elipses are?

EDIT:
In response to people saying this is impossible, I am willing to accept an inverse function that when given `y` returns a possible `x`.  In response to comments about the function not having an inverse, please note the contract that I have for `f`.  It is a `(number? -> number?)` mapping, and therefore has an inverse.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: Sorry, I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Daniel, I think we'd all be curious about what you're trying to achieve here? Is this simply an exploration of functional programming, or to you have some real use-case for a task? Because as both the answers so far indicate, this is mathematically impossible as presented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the general case, given an arbitrary function `f` you can't tell what's its inverse function. Even worse, a given function might not have an inverse *at all* - for example: the input function could perform an MD5 hash, which has no inverse. Sorry, your question has no answer.

Comment: Yeah you were right. I was thinking of the wrong thing. See the answer that I provided.

Comment: It is still possible to find the inverse of a bijective function in Racket. This is a common feature of many computer algebra systems.

Comment: but what if we assume the f function is bijective?

Answer (score 3):

Consider f(x)=x^2. This is a very simple function without an inverse. (because f(1)=f(-1) there are no unique inverse to y=1).

Since a very simple function might have no inverse, you cant't expect a general Scheme function to have an inverse.

Comment: Let's say that it's ok for the function to output one of the possibilities.

Comment: How about this one (define (f x) (let loop () (loop) 42))? Is there an inverse?

Comment: That isn't really a function. It is not a mapping from X -> Y.

Comment: Not in the mathematical sense, but it is a fine Scheme function.

Answer (score 2):

I knew that I had seen this before, but I couldn't remember how it worked. Now I remember, but I realized that I had been misleading in my question because the version I had seen assumed that we already had a function called `root` which would return one of the zeros of a provided function.  Given that function, it is pretty easy:

```
(define (inverse f)
  (lambda (y)
    (root (lambda (x) (- (f x) y)))))
```

It's pretty easy to see how this works. The inverse of a function is the `x` such that `f(x) = y`.  Obviously, the root of the function `f(x) - y = 0` is that `x`.

The place where I had gone wrong is that the best we can do for `root` is Newton's method or some other approximation.